# How do I pass the id of the NFT on Shimmer to a smart contract running on ShimmerEVM?

Tags: shimmer, nft, shimmerevm, solidity

I have this contract,

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.11;

import "https://github.com/iotaledger/wasp/blob/develop/packages/vm/core/evm/iscmagic/ISC.sol";

contract ProofContract {

    event NftEvent(IRC27NFT nft);

    function getNft() public {
        IRC27NFT memory nft = ISC.sandbox.getIRC27NFTData("0x96864d73590cd67651de5744c9239fe4bea653e88a4ba2a97fc9a333cb5c891a");
        emit NftEvent(nft);
    }
}
```

How do I pass the id of the NFT?
I get this error
[image]

Credit goes to alvorgar-dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with the so called `magic contract`:

> EVM and ISC are inherently very different platforms. Some EVM-specific actions (e.g., manipulating Ethereum tokens) are disabled, and EVM contracts can access ISC-specific functionality through the ISC Magic Contract.
> The Magic contract is an EVM contract deployed by default on every ISC chain, in the EVM genesis block, at address 0x1074000000000000000000000000000000000000. The implementation of the Magic contract is baked-in in the evm core contract); i.e. it is not a pure-Solidity contract.
> The Magic contract has several methods, which are categorized into specialized interfaces: ISCSandbox, ISCAccounts, ISCUtil and so on. You can access these interfaces from any Solidity contract by importing the ISC library.
> The Magic contract also provides proxy ERC20 contracts to manipulate ISC base tokens and native tokens on L2.

[Source](https://wiki.iota.org/shimmer/smart-contracts/guide/evm/magic/)

`asNFTID` from ISCTypes.sol calls:
`NFTID.wrap(bytes32(tokenID))`

So if you have the tokensID as bytes32 instead of uint256, you could call that directly

Here's an example of usage:
https://github.com/iotaledger/wasp/blob/develop/packages/vm/core/evm/iscmagic/ERC721NFTs.sol#L63

Credit goes to Jorge on the IOTA Discord